# Define variable in Ansible according complex condition

Tags: if-statement, syntax, ansible, yaml, conditional-statements

I need to define a variable in ansible according several conditions

I know the syntax

```
VARtodefined: "{{ 'Value1' if condition1 else 'Value2' }}"
```

I know I have the same result with the following other syntax

```
VARtodefined: "{% if condition1 %}'Value1'{% else %}'Value2'{% endif %}"
```

but I don't find the correct syntax for multiple condition (if-elsif-elsif-else)

I have for instance tried this without success

```
VARtodefined: "{% if condition1 %}'Value1'{% elsif condition2 %}'Value2'{% else %}'Value3'{% endif %}"
```

If have tried variant with `elif, elseif` but also without success

In my specific case condition1 is `OtherVar==XXX` and condition2 `OtherVar==YYY` (so in both case it depends the value of `OtherVar`)

So I'm looking for a working solution for this

```
VARtodefined: "{% if OtherVar==XXX %}'Value1'{% elsif  OtherVar==YYY%}'Value2'{% else %}'Value3'{% endif %}"
```

If have found a workaround to achieve my goal but I'm interested to know the correct syntax for future projects

Answer (score 2):

The example of the correct syntax is below. The task

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{% if item=='XXX' %}Value1
              {% elif  item=='YYY' %}Value2
              {% else %}Value3
              {% endif %}"
      loop: [XXX, ZZZ]
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: 'Value1 '
  msg: 'Value3 '
```

---

A simpler solution is putting the logic into a dictionary. For example

```yaml
conditions:
  XXX: Value1
  YYY: Value2
  default: Value3
```

Then, use it

```yaml
  - set_fact:
      VARtodefined: "{{ conditions[OtherVar]|
                        default(conditions.default) }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the expected syntax: `if` - `elif`/`else` - `endif`

please see and try example PB below:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    X: 2

  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      VARtodefined: "{% if X == 1 %}Value1{% elif X == 2 %}Value2{% else %}Value3{% endif %}"
    
  - debug:
      var: VARtodefined
```